# How use Set as base for TableView

Tags: javafx, set, tableview, javafx-8

I have developed some code and I have a `Set` of `User`s:

```
public class ParkCentral{
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Then, in a different class, I'm developing a GUI and a TableView of `User`s. 
The problem is that I can't create a `ObervableList` from a `Set`. And I would like that **changes on `ParkCentral.users` would be reflected on TableView.**

It is possible do this without changing `ParkCentral` implementation, without changing the `Set` to `List`?

Why TableView only works with ObservableList and not with ObservableSet or ObservableMap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why TableView only works with ObservableList and not with ObservableSet or ObservableMap?

A `TableView` presents an ordered collection of items. Neither `Map`
 nor `Set` fulfill those requirements (except for some implementations).

It's possible to listen to changes in the `Set` and make appropriate changes in the `List` though. This is not possible with just a `HashSet` though; there's simply no way to observe this collection; you'd always need to manually update the list after changes have been made.

Using a `ObservableSet` instead allows you to add a listener that does updates to a list though.

```
public class SetContentBinding<T> {

    private final ObservableSet<T> source;
    private final Collection<? super T> target;
    private final SetChangeListener<T> listener;

    public SetContentBinding(ObservableSet<T> source, Collection<? super T> target) {
        if (source == null || target == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;
        target.clear();
        target.addAll(source);
        this.listener = c -> {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                target.add(c.getElementAdded());
            } else {
                target.remove(c.getElementRemoved());
            }
        };
        source.addListener(this.listener);
    }

    /**
     * dispose the binding
     */
    public void unbind() {
        source.removeListener(listener);
    }

}
```

**Usage example:**

```
public class ParkCentral{
    private ObservableSet<User> users = FXCollections.observableSet(new HashSet<>());
}
```

```
new SetContentBinding(parkCentral.getUsers(), tableView.getItems());
```

Comment: I think that is the best option. The alterations in `users` of `ParkCentral` are minimal and the "binding" between 2 observables is easy to implement. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with custom columns:

```
 TableColumn<ParkCentral, Void> myCol = new TableColumn<>("NameColumn");        
        myCol.setPrefWidth(150);    
        myCol.setCellFactory(col->{            
            TableCell<ParkCentral, Void> cell = new TableCell<ParkCentral, Void>()
             {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) 
                {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {       
                       HBox h = new HBox();                  
                       ParckCentral myObj = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

                       //call any method/variable from myObj that you need
                       //and put the info that you want show on the cell on labels, buttons, images, etc

                       h.getChildren().addAll(label, button, etc...);
                       setGraphic(h);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
       });
```

Comment: `updateItem(item, empty)` is called frequently. You shouldn't create expensive objects in this method. If there is a need, you should implement your own `TableCell` and initialize those objects in the constructor.